# AtTask API (504) Gateway Timeout Error

Tags: attask

I'm having issues with task creation (POST) queries.  What I would like to know is this: is there POST query length limitation?

This string works:

```
http://012345.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/task?method=post&sessio
nID=01234567895f475b8a01234567898c05&name=Test 9&projectID=0123456789034af693e3d
e0123456789&assignedToID=0123456789016e913d9f3a00123456789&estCompletionDate=2015
-05-01T08:55:36:000-0500
```

and it's length is 252 characters.

However this one doesn't:

```
http://012345.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/task?method=post&sessio
nID=01234567895f475b8a01234567898c05&name=Test 11&projectID=0123456789034af693e3d
e0123456789&assignedToID=0123456789016e913d9f3a00123456789&estCompletionDate=2015
-05-01T08:55:36:000-0500
```

and it's length is 253 characters.

[UPDATE]

I have modified my query to include v4.0, so now it looks like:

```
 http://012345.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v4.0/login?method=post&...
```

However, I now receive the error *The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.*

To answer Jim's questions, the original error I was receiving was *The remote server retuned an error: (504) Gateway Timeout.* and the language I'm using is C#.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this also happens with PUT requests.

Comment: I also just finished experimenting with a variation on your suggestion, Jim; I used v3.0 rather than v4.0.  However, while _(400) Bad Request_ wasn't thrown again, I did receive the _(504) Gate Timeout_ error still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a query length limitation that I am aware of. I have used queries that are twice as long as the one you give an example of.

Try using a newer version of the api the newest api is 4.0. The post url would like like.

http://012345.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v4.0/task?method=post&sessio . . .

If you still have issues post the exact error message you are getting and what language you are using.

---

### UPDATE

Try using a JSON query to do the post. Using your above url example it would look like this.

Notice I am also just using a login method at the time of post instead of getting a session. So change the username and password to your attask login info.

See if this will give you better results and let me know.

https://012345.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v4.0/task?updates={"name":"Test 11","projectID":"0123456789034af693e3de0123456789","assignedToID":"0123456789016e913d9f3a00123456789","estCompletionDate":"2015-05-01T08:55:36:000-0500"}&method=post&username=admin@user.attask&password=user

Comment: If you are getting a 504 error. please post the entire url query of the post. Without username and passwords (of course). Let me see if I can figure out what is going on.

Comment: In my original post, the second query I posted (or, rather, the one that doesn't work) is similar to the entire POST query that I've tried to use.  The only difference between what I use and the ones I posted is that the various IDs have been changed to be incorrect; otherwise they are exactly the same (including the length).

Comment: Ok, I tried your second suggestion directly in the browser first, and it was successful.  However, when I made the necessary modifications in my code, I still received the _(504) Gateway Timeout_ error.  I then further modified my code to replace sessionID with my login information, but same result.

Comment: The fact that you placed it in the browser and it worked is a good sign. That means the connection to attask works. Your API call in your code should get the same results. It may have something to do with SSL make sure your call is using https://. Could you post an example of the api call you are using in c#?

Comment: The call (which is pre-written in the C# Sample Code provided on the site) my program was making used http://, not https://.  I made that switch, and it is now working fine.  Thanks very much for the help!